# Moodle 3.1 [[setting:themecolor]] does not produce data

Tags: css, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.1 and in my plugin I want to catch the theme color
so  I use  background-color: [[setting:themecolor]]; in styles.css file related to my plugin but the variable does not produce the data I need and the browser shows me an error.
Any idea why it is not working?
Thanks

Comment: What type of plugin are you trying to create? (Local, Activity, Enrol, Theme, etc) and the background color of what are you trying to catch? Of some specific page? Which variable are you referring to?

Comment: a Local plugin.
setting:themecolor